# How to Find elements using multiple attributes

Tags: selenium

I tried to find element from html using the id which is having numbers at the end but when I running the scripts the element is getting changed and can't find the element while running.Please suggest me the best way to find dynamic elements in web application using selenium

Comment: Please show the code you've tried first. We're happy to help when you have a specific implementation question.

Answer (score 2):

> the id which is having numbers at the end

Assuming the `id` has something static in the beginning, you can check that `id` starts with something you know it would start with. Sample in Java:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id^=something_static]"));
```

Here the `[id^=something_static]` is a *CSS selector* and `^=` is a starts-with notation.

Answer (score 1):

Same could be done with `xpath`. `Python` sample will looks like follow:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "your_static_part")]')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in python you can use time.sleep() function and pass any numeric value like time.sleep(10).It is done for your page to fully load then you can extract the value of those html elements using selenium's attributes like-:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('')
driver.find_element_by_link_text('')
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('').
```